# How do I install EZ publish plaform from scratch?

Tags: ezpublish

How do I install EZ publish plaform from scratch on windows7?

1. I have installed xaamp, php and mysql.

It would be convenient if you can guide step by step.

Comment: https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Installing+eZ+Publish+on+Windows

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation should help you :-)
https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Installing+eZ+Publish+on+Windows